# Шаблоны в модуле .cpp?

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, модульность

Такая ошибка:

Создается класс шаблон в

**module1.h**

```
template <typename тип>
struct A
{
void func();
};
extern A<int> a;
```

**module1.cpp**

```
template <typename тип>
void A<тип>::func(){}

A<int> a;
```

**module2.h**

```
#include "module1.h"
struct B
{
B();
};
extern B b;
```

**module2.cpp**

```
B::B()
{
a.func();
}

B b;
```

error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ ""public: void __cdecl A<int>::func(void)" (?func@?$A@H@@QEAAXXZ)"

Нашел тему, где сказали, что по стандарту использовать шаблоны в .cpp можно, но компиляторы этого не позволяют.

Если шаблоны убрать, то всё работает.

В чём здесь проблема?
Ведь тип чётко задан

```
A<int> a;
```

Есть ли возможность использовать шаблоны таким образом?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Весь фокус в том, что шаблон инстанциируется в таком случае в файле module1.cpp. Инстанциирование экземпляра шаблона происходит "по требованию". Так же и создание кода его методов. В модуле module1.cpp не было вызова метода func() и его код не был создан. Поэтому линковщик и не находит его.

Общий вывод: лучше все шаблоны со всеми определениями всех их членов засовывать в хедеры.

Comment: А кроме вызова шаблона по требованию, есть ли какие нибудь механизмы в С++? 
export не работает. 

В заголовки помещать, самое простое решение.

Насколько разумно создавать инстанциатор шаблона, на подобии конструктора для класса?

Все шаблонные классы наследуются от класса имеющего bool и метод is_instance().

В начало конструктора помещать вызов всех методов класса, которые сразу прекращают выполнение
if(is_instance()==false){return;}

после всех вызовов методов
set_instance(true)

Comment: Просто хочется знать какие решения в таком случаи используют.

Может есть где нибудь развёрнутая тема?

Comment: А зачем это нужно? Читай Джосатис, Вандервуд "Шаблоны в С++"

Comment: Да просто в ряде случаев, это может привести к увеличению компиляции.
Книга интересная. спасибо.

Comment: К увеличению чего?

Comment: По поводу шаблонов читать [здесь][1]

[1]:http://www.comeaucomputing.com/4.0/docs/userman/export.html

Comment: @mikillskegg 
имею ввиду время компиляции.

@gecube 

в visual studio 

export вообще никак не помечается. То есть он не является ключевым словом. Может в настройках можно задать?

Так нашел решение в указанной книге.
Явное инстанцирование класса для указанного типа


    В module1.h
    
    template class A<int>; 


Еще один момент:
как правильно?
инстанцирование 

инстанциирование

Comment: Шаблоны вообще могут очень сильно увеличить время компиляции.

Comment: @manking, правильно - инстанцирование
@mikillskegg, не только. Код с шаблонами еще и сложнее отлажить. А однажды компилятор даже сообщение об ошибке не выдавал, а просто валился в segfault. Это был криво написанный шаблон, а собиралось msvc2010

Comment: Ха, у меня однажды компилятор вошел в бесконечный цикл ))) Метапрограммирование - очень забавная штука.