# Cсылка на неразрешенный внешний символ

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Имеется класс выведенный в отдельный Z.h файл с таким содержимым:

```
#pragma once

template <class T>
class A
{
    T a;

public:
    explicit A(int b);
    ~A(){}
};
```

и Z.cpp с таким:

```
#include "Z.h"


template<typename T>
A<T>::A(int b)
{
    a = b;
}
```

Вроде бы все элементарно и просто, но при попытке создать объект и скомпилировать программу VS13 выдает такую ошибку:

> error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "public: __thiscall A::A(int)" (??0?$A@H@@QAE@H@Z) в функции _main

Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем проблема? Если методы сделать "inline" или просто убрать шаблоны, то все работает прекрасно, но стоит вынести в отдельный файл и все ломается.

Comment: Вообще шаблоны обычно не выносятся в срр файл, так как его специализация происходит в момент компиляции. Это делают, но костыли, костыли. В данной примере вам надо include В обратную сторону - в h файле сделать include с файла прямо в классе. Но лучше откажитесь)

Comment: И уже был такой вопрос на SO: [ТЫК](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/164626/%D0%A8%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8B-%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B5-cpp)